# How to set input state angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have some form with angularjs valid/invalid states.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : createForm.name.$invalid && !createForm.name.$pristine , 'has-success': createForm.name.$valid}">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.filterName"  ng-minlength="1" required/>
            <span ng-show="createForm.name.$invalid && !createForm.name.$pristine">Name shouldn't be empty</span>
            <span ng-show="isDublicateColumn($parent.filterName)">Name already exists</span>
        </div>
```

How do I set input to invalid state based on result of `isDublicateColumn($parent.filterName)` ?

Or is any better way to change bootstrap state to `'has-error'` when `isDublicateColumn($parent.filterName)` return true ?

Comment: An easy way would be to use UI.Utils Validate http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/validate

Answer (score 1):

Should do the job

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 
                   'has-error' : (isDublicateColumn($parent.filterName) || createForm.name.$invalid && !createForm.name.$pristine) ,  
                             'has-success': createForm.name.$valid}">
```

Comment: It's not the right place for it and it doesn't work.

Comment: I use it multiple times in a rich validtion form. It should work, aslong as isDublicateColumn() works as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<form>` instead of `<div>`, an alternative solution is to create a custom validation directive.

```
app.directive('noDuplicateColumn', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var isValid = !scope.isDublicateColumn(viewValue);

        modelCtrl.$setValidity('duplicateColumn', isValid);

        return isValid ? viewValue : undefined;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and put it at your input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="filterName" ng-minlength="1" required no-duplicate-column />
```

For the full example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/O7MZX8lAk6lUjHnkgnVG?p=preview